# Python - Memory limit exceeded during Google App Engine deployment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, limit, google-app-engine-python

I am creating a Python project and deploying it to Google App Engine.

When I use the deployed link in another project, I get the following error message in Google Cloud Logging:

```
Exceeded hard memory limit of 256 MB with 667 MB after servicing 0 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
```

So, I looked at [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#second-gen-runtimes) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=python#automatic_scaling) link and here are the main points:

- | Instance Class | Memory Limit | CPU Limit | Supported Scaling Types |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | F1 (default) | 256 MB | 600 MHz | automatic |
  | F2 | 512 MB | 1.2 GHz | automatic |
  | F4 | 1024 MB | 2.4 GHz | automatic |
  | F4_1G | 2048 MB | 2.4 GHz | automatic |
- `instance_class: F2`

The error says the limit is 256 MB, but 667 MB is recorded. The memory limit for F1 and the memory limit for F2 are less than 667 MB. So I added `instance_class: F2` to `app.yaml` and changed `F2` to `F4`.

When I do the above, I get the following error in Google Cloud Logging:

```
Exceeded hard memory limit of 1024 MB with 1358 MB after servicing 0 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
```

This is a bit strange since the recorded memory is from 667 MB to 1358 MB.

The memory limit of F4_1G is over 1358 MB, so I changed `instance_class: F4` to `instance_class: F4_1G`. But it shows me the following error in Google Cloud Logging:

```
Exceeded hard memory limit of 2048 MB with 2194 MB after servicing 0 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
```

This is very strange since the recorded memory goes from 667 MB to 1358 MB to 2194 MB.

## Update:

I have reproduced this problem without additional instance class.

Please refer error log below:

```
0: {
logMessage: "Exceeded soft memory limit of 256 MB with 924 MB after servicing 0 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml."
severity: "CRITICAL"
time: "2022-10-19T06:00:39.747954Z"
}
1: {
logMessage: "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."
severity: "INFO"
time: "2022-10-19T06:00:39.748029Z"
}
2: {
logMessage: "While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml."
severity: "WARNING"
time: "2022-10-19T06:00:39.748031Z"
}
```

## Another finding:

When the app is running in local terminal, it consumes 1 GB - 3 GB memory to running the app fully loaded which takes around 30 seconds. Meanwhile, the memory usage is 700 MB - 750 MB during idle state, and 750 MB - 800 MB to serve single request.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? How can I fix this error and use the deployed link successfully? I would appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks as if your App (startup module) is consuming a lot of memory. GAE starts loading your App and then runs out of memory. The more memory it has access to (via the instance_class), the more of your App it's able to load before it gets cut off. This would account for why you have the varying memory consumption as you changed the instance class. Take a look at your log to see where your App gets cut off and see if you can spot/fix the memory bottlenectk

Comment: Hi @NoCommandLine, according to the table, F4_1G has the most memory and no other instance class has more memory than F4_1G

Comment: I understand that but I was postulating a theory on why you were seeing your App's memory vary from 667 to 2194 as you changed the instance. Bottom line, I suggest looking for memory leaks/seeing if you can optimize your code which is why I said to look at your logs to see where your App gets cut off. I once had a similar issue with an App that dealt with Google Sheets and it turned out that my issue was caused by my code copying my existing rows in memory (as part of duplicate process).

Comment: You could also be running into the difference in entrypoint settings[1] between instance classes, where the larger instance sizes default to having more workers.  As part of your testing, try different settings for `--workers` (starting with 1), and see what happens.  For example, in your app.yaml, set: 

`instance_class: F4_1G`
`entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT --workers 1 main:app`

If that works, you can try reducing the instance class (or increasing workers, if you want concurrency).

[1]https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#entrypoint_best_practices

Comment: Hi @msl, I have tried adding `instance_class: F4_1G`
 `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 -w 8 main:app` in `app.yaml` but unfortunately it didn't work out. I think the expected solution is to overcome memory spike (1 GB - 3 GB) during deployment. Once the app is brought up, the memory usage is back to normal (700 MB - 800 MB).

Comment: Please post your answer so that other community members will find this helpful.

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I store larger files from local to cloud. Then I successfully deployed the code to Google App Engine without any errors.